# Mongoose - altering the contents of query result records

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection of records which have certain specific properties that I need for internal use, however when I send the results back to the user I would like these properties to be re-arranged.

Specifically I have a `geo` array that I would like to break up into `lat` and `lng` properties.

I am using Mongoose, and was wondering if there was a way to use a `pre/post` hook (I've used it for 'save') on record results during searches, to modify the records before the results are returned.

So, in the DB if we had:

```
{
  name: 'Foo Bar',
  geo: [-0.12, 32.17]
},
{
  name: 'Pizza',
  geo: [-0.09, 34.51]
}
```

The results from the query would be:

```
{
  name: 'Foo Bar',
  lat: 32.17,
  lng: -0.12
},
{
  name: 'Pizza',
  lat: 34.51,
  lng: -0.09
}
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah on your model definition use the post-init event to do that transformation. More info here:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#post

```
Schema
    .post('init', function (doc) {
        //do your stuff

    })
```

Comment: Hi Biba, thanks for your reply. Could you give me an example of what I'd do with the doc object. Do I just start adding properties and deleting things I don't want the user to see? Will this effect searches?

Comment: Doc is your document/model that you need to modify. You can add properties as you wish, they are not part of your Mongoose model unless you declare them so but for what you need i suspect you just want to format the returned object to match your specs. .post-init is called for every search result handing you the doc to do what you need to it.